# getJSON Ajax para JSON com múltiplos objetos

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Para buscar dados num *JSON* simples, como:

```
{
    "chave1":"valor1",
    "chave2":"valor2"
}
```

Utilizo algo assim:

```
$.getJSON(dados, function(json) {
    $.each(json, function() {
        $('#r').append("<p>"+this.chave1+"</p>");
    });
})
```

Mas o caso agora é um *JSON* no formato:

```
{"tab":[{
    "urlimg":"1.jpg",
    "nome":"Jhonatan",
    "sobrenome":"Pereira"},
    {"urlimg":"1.jpg",
    "nome":"Jhonatan",
    "sobrenome":"Pereira"}],
"dados":[{
    "algum":"valor",
    "qualquer":"valor2"}],
"outro":[{
    "numero_versao":"1",
    "nome_versao":"v0.1B"}]
}
```

Isso porque o PHP retorna 3 consultas, e preciso passar todos os resultados em uma única requisição.

Ajudas?

Comment: Isso é simples. Que parte desse JSON queres usar?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui e diz qual é a parte (ou como) precisas usar no teu código: https://jsfiddle.net/qfjtoza7/

Comment: Fala Sergio, eu preciso pegar as "chave-valor" de cada sessão por vez. No caso, precisaria do carregamento de "tab", em um segundo momento de "dados", etc. Isso é para a criação de um álbum de fotos dinâmico, onde no Json  o primeiro são os anos, o segundo os meses e o terceiro as fotos. Pra facilitar, podemos trocar tab, dados e outro por "ano", "mes" e "fotos"

Comment: Ok, e viste o meu jsFiddle? consegues perceber como estou a usar o JSON lá? é isso que procuras?

Comment: Exatamente isso :) Só responder para eu votar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma como você trabalha não irá mudar, o que você deve se atentar é ao tratamento que será feito sobre cada parte do JSON que retornar. Veja:

```
$.getJSON(dados, function(json) {

  //para cada *value* é necessário indicar o nome da coluna(índice): value.indice
  //pois no json informado, *value* trata-se de um array

  //tratamento da "tab"
  $.each(json.tab, function(key, value) {
     $('#tab').append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + value.urlimg +  "</p>" );
     $('#tab').append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + value.nome +  "</p>" );
     $('#tab').append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + value.sobrenome +  "</p>" );
  });

  //tratamento dos "dados"
  $.each(json.dados, function(key, value) {
     $('#dados').append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + value.algum + "</p>" );
  });

  //tratamento da "outro"
  $.each(json.outro, function(key, value) {
     $('#outro').append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + value.nome_versao + "</p>" );
  });
})
```

Isso contando que você saiba quais parametros serão retornados. Caso você não tenha conhecimento mas quer que ele retorne todos os parâmetros em determinadas div's também é possível assim:

```
$.getJSON(dados, function(json) {
  //para cara parametro execute o $.each
  $.each(json, function(key, value) {
      //defino em qual sub-array do json estará sendo trabalhado
      var param = json[key];
      //usa o nome do 'param' para definir qual div, EX: #tab => "#"+'tab'
      $.each(param,function(key, value){
        $('#' + key).append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + value + "</p>" );
      });
  });
})
```

Agora vejo que você está trabalhando com o jQuery. Aconselho que você procure saber mais sobre Javascript puro pois além de ser mais "legível" também economiza códigos em certos casos como no **$.each()**. OBS: Isso não quer dizer que você não possa misturar os dois, assim:

```
//sabendo quais campos serão enviados
$.getJSON(dados, function(json) {
  //tratamento da "tab"
  for(var key in json.tab){
    $('#tab').append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + json.tab + "</p>" );
  };
  //tratamento dos "dados"
  for(var key in json.dados){
    $('#dados').append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + json.dados + "</p>" );       
  };
  //tratamento da "outro"
  for(var key in json.outro){
    $('#outro').append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + json.outro + "</p>" );
  };
})

//sem saber quais campos mas querendo colocar todos (2º exemplo)
$.getJSON(dados, function(json) {
  //para cara sub-objeto, trate seus parâmetros
  for (var p in json)
      //defino em qual sub-array do json estará sendo trabalhado
      var param = json[p];
      //usa o nome do 'param' para definir qual div, EX: #tab => "#"+'tab'
      for(var key in param)
        $('#' + key).append( "<p> key=" + key + "& value=" + param[key] + "</p>" );
      });
  });
})
```

Comment: Está retornando um objeto no "valor":

 _tab_
key=0& value=[object Object]

key=1& value=[object Object]

_dados_
key=0& value=[object Object]

_outro_
key=0& value=[object Object]

Comment: Consegui, ao invés de _value_, coloquei _value.urlimg_, _value.nome, value.sobrenome_, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode continuar utilizando da mesma forma, só com uma iteração a mais sobre o objeto retornado.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON('dados.json', function (dados) {

       var objKeys = Object.keys(dados);

       for (var key in objKeys) {
           imprimirConsulta(objKeys[key], dados);
       }
   });

   function imprimirConsulta(consulta, dados) {
       if (!dados.hasOwnProperty(consulta)) {
           console.error('Dados não possuem consulta', consulta);
           return;
       }

       var $div = $('<div></div>');
       $div.append('<div>' + consulta.toUpperCase() + '</div>');

       var obj = dados[consulta];

       obj.forEach(function (obje) {
           $.each(obje, function (chave, valor) {
               $div.append('<div>Chave: ' + chave + '    Valor: ' + valor + '</div>');
           });

           $div.append('<div style="margin: 5px;"></div>');
       });

       $('.content').append($div);
       $('.content').append('<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>')
   }
});
```